# using different stylesheet for IE10 and IE11

Tags: html, css

Other than javascript, is there another way to use a different style-sheet for a web app in IE10 and IE11?

Comment: Sadly, I can't think of anything besides a small detector library like Modernizr (that's JS though). Would you mind giving a brief description of the problem in question? ie, applying some new CSS property to IE11, and gracefully degrading IE10. If you know how an older browser will treat unknown CSS properties, you can sometimes mix them.

Comment: Since the conditional commenting was phased out as of IE10, ive been researching seeing if there are any other ways, other than javascript, to serve a seperate stylesheet to my web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX):

> **Important** As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't supported by the browser.

@yglodt you can not differentiate between 10 and 11 as 10 -- dropped support.

Looked over fallback strategy, not very impressed - you will test for feature availability.

You can use any language (*JavaScript*, *PHP*, *Python*, etc) to check agent and take action. Not the best, but works in desperate mode.

Comment: I would advise against using the ***user-agent*** string to detect the browser version. This string can be spoofed or changed. In short, it ***cannot*** be trusted.

Comment: I agree with War10ck, but for different reasons; someone's on their own if they're using developer tools to spoof themselves in some way. But my reasoning is that while it is tricky, for long-term survival of your page it's really worth it to find CSS that works well in all browsers, and still looks usable and readable in older browsers. "Normalizers" can sometimes help with this.

Comment: @Katana314 you are totally right and I agree. The goal (dream) is to have 100% coverage of HTML/CSS/JS in browsers and 100% compliant behavior. Until then I think normalizers and the like are a good option. Side note: I have been working/experimenting more with high quality (CSS) resets and using only percent and em for all size and positioning. So far so good! And for the record, I have only had to use agent detection and tweaking a few rare times and usually in an agency environment where craft is a distant 10th place.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for breaking your constraint, but this would be the only solution:

with this you can ad a IE10 class when the browser is indeed IE10:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<script>if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';}</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

This works because of @datamafia's answer.

Now you can target `.ie10` in your CSS and have different style for IE10 then for IE11 (*IE11 is getting the rest of CSS*)

Comment: If that works, it's kind of impressive. But, sadly, you did break the "other than javascript" constraint, at which point I'd motion for a less hacky approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with conditional comments in html. Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX

Edit:

Some people mentioned that IE11 dropped support for conditional comments... which is sad.

Otoh you can still do it old-school by serving different stylesheets for the IE user-agent, with server-side browser sniffing.

Comment: From that page: "As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode."